# Pandas multiIndex slicing by aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas Series (S) that has an index like:

```py
bar  one  a
          b
     two  a
          b
baz  one  a
.
.
```

I have a conditional function that returns a lower dimensional index. What I am doing is performing something like `S.groupby(level=(0,1)).median() > 1`

This returns a Series with Index like so:

```py
bar  one 
baz  two
foo  one 
. 
.
```

How do I slice the original Series with the lower dimensional index?

I know I can reset index and select rows using .isin but I would like to use MultiIndex if possible.

Thanks in advance!

===

Here is what the actual Series (s) looks like:

```
BATCH    ITEM  SEQ   X   Y 
D1M2     765   6005  -5   0    5.085
         769   6005  -3  -2    6.174
         767   6005  -4  -1    5.844
         769   6005  -3  -1    5.702
                     -4   2    5.154
         767   6005  -3   2    5.337
                     -2   4    5.683
                      3   0    6.178
         769   6005  -3   2    5.128
         765   6005   1  -4    4.791
```

I perform the following operation:

```
sm = s.groupby(level=(0,1,2)).median()
sigma = sm.std()
sms = sm[sm - sm.median() < sigma/2]
```

Now sms looks like:

```
BATCH    ITEM  SEQ 
D1M2     765   6005    4.938
         769   6005    5.428
```

Now I want to slice the series s that match the index in sms *only*.

So I want this slice of *s* (that matches the index of *sms*):

```
BATCH    ITEM  SEQ   X   Y 
D1M2     765   6005  -5   0    5.085
         769   6005  -3  -2    6.174
                     -3  -1    5.702
                     -4   2    5.154
                     -3   2    5.128
         765   6005   1  -4    4.791
```

Comment: Please provide a full sample and the expected result to get help please. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible only if your index levels are the same which is not the case here because in `s`, you have `['BATCH', 'ITEM', 'SEQ', 'X', 'Y']` and in `sms`, you have only `['BATCH', 'ITEM', 'SEQ']`.

You have to drop `X` and `Y` levels before to match indexes:

```
# Statically
>>> s[s.index.droplevel(['X', 'Y']).isin(sms.index)]

# Dynamically
>>> s[s.index.droplevel(s.index.names.difference(sms.index.names)).isin(sms.index)]

# Output
BATCH  ITEM  SEQ   X   Y 
DIM2   765   6005  -5   0    5.085
       769   6005  -3  -2    6.174
                       -1    5.702
                   -4   2    5.154
                   -3   2    5.128
       765   6005   1  -4    4.791
dtype: float64
```